# What is the difference between sum(attribute) and attribute.sum()?

Tags: python, list

I have an example: Assume I have an list named arr and I want to print the sum of the list. Here is my code.

```
arr = [1,3,5]
print(sum(arr)) #9
print(arr.sum()) #AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

However, I see that most people use `attribute.sum()` instead of `sum(attribute)`.

Can you tell me the difference between them?

Comment: Error is clear saying that there is no method on the list called `sum`

Comment: You *don't* have an array. You have a list. You're getting lists mixed up with [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `sum()` is a function, not a `method`. Second off, like others have pointed out in the comments, you do not have an `array` but in fact a `list`. There are two possible syntaxes. `sum(a)`, where `a` is a list. Which then adds up all the numbers in the list and returns the sum. The second syntax would be `sum(a, b)` where it returns the `a` list plus `b` .

The correct way to use the `sum()` function would look something like this:

```
arr = [1,3,5] 
  

Sum = sum(arr) 
print(Sum) 
  

Sum = sum(arr, 10) 
print(Sum)
```